# Problems typing functions using typescript generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Case #1

I am getting error:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'T'

```
function test<T>(arr:Array<T>, item:T) {

const idxReplaced = arr.findIndex(element=> element.name === item.name)
  return {
     ...arr.slice(0, idxReplaced),
     ...arr.slice(idxReplaced+1)
  }

}

interface IItem {
  name: number
}


console.log(test<IItem>([{name:1},{name:3}], {name: 3}))
```

---

Case #2

I want to change every name property in object array according its name.

I am getting errors:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'ICurrentItem'

and

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IItem'.

```
interface IItem {
  user: string,
}
  
interface ICurrentItem {
  [key: string]: IItem
}

function test<IItem>(arr:Array<IItem>, item:IItem) {

return arr.reduce((acc:ICurrentItem,el:IItem)=> {
    acc[el.user] = item[el.user]
    return acc
  },{})
}   

console.log(test([{user:'info'},{user:'test'}], {user: 'some info'}))
```

---

You can test it here: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCoD4AUAhgE7EBcAgqYQJ464A0iMqAtmdgJSIDeAUHwgIMzACYAPAEooADgBtCEFKMQBeRCWIA6YDDCiAkvpTj8KOSlYowUVbkTnL1qFrCEra1epaXX7lJx8xChQIMRI-IiIWjGaWmhyMEr4AAxMMBLS8orKnAx8UTFacQlJKPgZUrIKSqIA1ACMgQC+Aq18eqjEwDmIBgZsvAWIblZkIyCsAEYoxHztgsJwFlpycADm+KgYmP1sBADaPKMoZA3NDMf+ZADMzQC6TFdjiHecnEA)

Comment: You need to give `T` an upper bound, like `<T extends {name: string}>`.

Comment: No it is not all even in 1 case(

Comment: Please post the desired output of `console.log(test([{user:'info'},{user:'test'}], {user: 'some info'})`.  I can explain the error but I don't understand what you want it to do.

Comment: Hey so I edited your post to format it better and I realized that you had edited your code to a more "correct" version.  I am changing it back to what you originally had to illustrate the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Case #1

@kaya3's comment is correct.  Your function assumes that your array elements and your `item` variable (both type `T`) will have a `.name` property.  So you must ensure that all possible types for `T` include at least a `name`.

```
function test1<T extends { name: any }>(arr: Array<T>, item: T) {

  const idxReplaced = arr.findIndex(element => element.name === item.name)
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, idxReplaced),
    ...arr.slice(idxReplaced + 1)
  ]
}
```

You don't need to set the generic here because it is inferred as `<{name: number}>` based on the arguments.

```
console.log(test1([{ name: 1 }, { name: 3 }], { name: 3 }))
```

#### Case #2

```
function test<IItem>(arr:Array<IItem>, item:IItem) {
```

This right here shows a misunderstanding of generic type parameters.  You can use any name for the generic type and `<IItem>` here is basically `<T>` with another name.  It is a local type variable that bears no relation to the `interface IItem`.

I suspect what you meant to do was something like this, where the generic type must extend `{user: string}`:

```
function test2<T extends IItem>(arr: Array<T>, item: T) {
```

Or to not have it be generic at all, and simply add types to the arguments:

```
function test2(arr: Array<IItem>, item: IItem) {
```

We are building an object `acc` where the key is a `string` from the item's `user` property and the value is an `item`.  You've got that part typed correctly.  It's fine to access `acc[el.user]` because `acc` has a string index.

But what are you trying to to do with `item[el.user]`?  `el.user` is the username `string` and `item` is an `IItem`.  It does not have a property that corresponds to the `user` value.

In your example:

```
console.log(test2([{ user: 'info' }, { user: 'test' }], { user: 'some info' }))
```

You would be accessing `({ user: 'some info' }).info` and `({ user: 'some info' }).test`.  Typescript is right to warn you that those don't exist.

I'm genuinely not sure what you are trying to achieve here.  If you meant to turn an array of items into an object keyed by the username then you don't need a second argument `item` for that.  That would be:

```
interface IItem {
  user: string,
}

interface ICurrentItem<T extends IItem> {
  [key: string]: T
}

function test2<T extends IItem>(arr: Array<T>) {

  return arr.reduce((acc: ICurrentItem<T>, el: T) => {
    acc[el.user] = el
    return acc
  }, {})
}

console.log(test2([{ user: 'info' }, { user: 'test' }]))
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wOaARm)

**edit:** *"I want to change every name property in object array according its name."*

I think maybe you want [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

This code replaces the `user` property of the array elements with the user property from `item.user` ("some info").

```
function test<T extends IItem>(arr: Array<T>, item: T) {

  return arr.map(el => ({ ...el, user: item.user }));
}

console.log(test([{ user: 'info' }, { user: 'test' }], { user: 'some info' }))
// output: [{ "user": "some info" }, { "user": "some info" }]
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot to figure it out!

Comment: but how I can descrive exactly my case 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=77#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKsgW2QbwFDLIhyYQBcyAzmFKAOYA0eAvnnqJLIiqgMICuUKBHAYImADwAVZBAAekEABNKaMZgB8uAsgDaAawgBPCtVog6AXQpSWbPDH4gEYYAHsQySNQBM02QoiKmpYGgAUcEIUAIJCcEbSGgzIwFgUcCBGAJTaOsJggp6RUAB0wkr8SGERCAgUfILColiJyRAANjY5ALxa+ISEiAi6HSXEpJbI3SlYI+1jJBCWOoT5hchDOszJOMxZdngIHpRu7RAl7W50Yd5gPmG6OESLFADk4xCvyNu4z6RvHy+zEsOw+ZFeJ1IKRAMDcrz2WSAA

Comment: instead any what can I use

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/WJ9XVm You need the values of the `name` property to match the keys of the `item` object.